# How can you check and analyze SSL ports other than 443?

Tags: tls, known-vulnerabilities, vulnerability-scanners, secure-renegotiation

I tried

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=imap.spamarrest.com%3A993&hideResults=on

but it said

> Ports other than 443 not supported

I need to check imap.spamarrest.com:993

Comment: do you need a site or can you run a tool on a machine?

Comment: I can run a tool on my machine, but I thought a site would be more authoritative and configured correctly, and up-to-date, and easier to use.

Comment: I recommend to use [`sslyze`](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze/releases).

Comment: What do you want it to analyze? What results are you expecting? The same range of results that ssllabs.com provides?

Comment: Vote for SSL Labs feature request https://github.com/ssllabs/ssllabs-scan/issues/441

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## 2021-02-28 Update: GeoCerts and SSLPing

Two new entries on the list. They've been around for a while. Both of these can do ports other than 443:

- https://www.geocerts.com/ssl-checker
- https://sslping.com/ <= requires (free) account to check ports apart from 443

I prefer SSLPing for it's *"just the essentials!"* results interface.

## ImmuniWeb (new service; formerly HTBridge)

https://www.immuniweb.com/ssl

Example: [Report for `imap.spamarrest.com:993`](https://www.immuniweb.com/ssl/?id=Jsi2VVD1)

---

There are a few. But none even close to what SSL Labs does.

Here are two sample sites.

- [DigiCert SSL Tools](https://ssltools.digicert.com/checker/) (one gets redirected to this site from formerly mentioned https://ssltools.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/)
- http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/report/?fqdn=imap.spamarrest.com%3A993&protocol=https

#### Port 443 limit is by design

SSL Labs does this on purpose. I didn't know this. But here's the rationale. It's listed inside their *[Read This First](https://community.qualys.com/docs/DOC-5077)* document:

> **Commonly Requested Features**

- **Checking of IP addresses without hostnames;** SSL Labs is designed to test public web servers services. We define public as having a DNS record and running on the official port for the given service (e.g., 443 for HTTPS). We don't allow direct checking of IP addresses because we don't consider such services public.
- **Checking of web servers on non-standard ports;** see the previous point.

Comment: SSLPing has shutdown https://www.theregister.com/2022/04/12/sslping_to_ping_no_more/

Answer (score 8):

I use https://testssl.sh/

> testssl.sh is a free command line tool which checks a server's service on any port for the support of TLS/SSL ciphers, protocols as well as recent cryptographic flaws and more.

It also works well on Windows 10 if you have the 'Windows Subsystem for Linux' installed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/commandline/wsl/install_guide

Answer (score 2):

There are some alternatives to Qualys SSL Labs which permit analyzing ports other than 443, but their functionality may much narrower:

- [CypherCraft](https://www.cyphercraft.io/)
- [DigiCert SSL Tools](https://ssltools.digicert.com/checker/)
- [NameCheap SSL Checker](https://decoder.link/sslchecker/)
- [SSL Shopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)

or you can use open source software without any restrictions:

- [CipherScan](https://github.com/mozilla/cipherscan)
- [CryptoLyzer](https://gitlab.com/coroner/cryptolyzer)
- [sslscan](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan)
- [SSLyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze)
- [`testssl.sh`](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh)

Answer (score 0):

For me it didn't work out for any of above.

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html was giving cached old results. Even testssls.sh won't give any output.

ssls.com support has given me new way to check which is working:

https://decoder.link/sslchecker/example.com/443

https://decoder.link/sslchecker/example.com/8000 //port 8000